# multiple kafka clusters on single zookeeper ensemble

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I currently have a 3 node Kafka cluster which connects to base chroot path in my zookeeper ensemble.

```
zookeeper.connect=172.12.32.123:2181,172.11.43.211:2181,172.18.32.131:2181
```

Now, I want to add a new 5 node Kafka cluster which will connect to some other chroot path in the same zookeeper ensemble.

```
zookeeper.connect=172.12.32.123:2181,172.11.43.211:2181,172.18.32.131:2181/cluster/2
```

Will these configurations work as in the relative paths for the two chroots? I understand that the original Kafka cluster should have been connected on some path other than the base chroot path for better isolation.

Also, is it good to have same zookeeper ensemble across Kafka clusters? The [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#zkops) says that it is generally better to have isolated zookeeper ensembles for different clusters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only limited to a single Zookeeper cluster, then it should work out fine with a unique chroot that doesn't collide with the other cluster's znodes.

It is not "good" to share, no, because Zookeeper losing quorum causes two clusters to be down, but again if you're limited on hardware, then it'll still work

Note: You can only afford to lose one ZK server with 3 nodes in the cluster, which is why a cluster of 5 is recommended

Comment: so lets say i put the zookeeper.connect details serverIP:Port/path

So will this dump all metadata for in /path which I provide for the another kafka cluster?

Comment: @ShubhamSaroj It's called a chroot in Zookeeper, but yes, you can use unique chroots for sharing the same Zookeeper cluster with multiple clients. Using Kafka as an example, each broker must have the same chroot to form a cluster.

Comment: is it important to mention the chroot with all IP of ZK? like this,
```zookeeper.connect=ip1:port/chroot1, ip2:port/chroot1``` or ```zookeeper.connect=ip1:port, ip2:port/chroot1``` this should do?

Comment: @ShubhamSaroj Do you get any errors when you try either? I believe it's only the second format, but you will want to use zookeeper-shell to double check

Comment: Yes the second format is working for me and also verified with zookeeper-shell